# Debian 10 see connected IP to port 3306

Tags: mysql, debian, port

I am using Debian 10 as a MySQL server and I have opened my firewall on port 3306 TCP to allow some others to connect to databases on the MySQL server. At the moment port 3306 is open to all but I want to only open this for fixed IP's. Now how can I see the IP's that are connected to my MySQL on port 3306?
I made a testscript and ran if from somewhere else, it connects ok and retrieves all MySQL data but netstat or nmap is not showing that connection at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for netstat.

```
netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | grep :3306 | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

It shows the ip's connected as well as the number of connections by that same ip.

Comment: Tried that but it is not showing an active connection even though someone is connected.

Comment: @James Have you tried using mysql itself? For example this query: `select host from information_schema.processlist;`

Comment: Is it possible that you are connecting via ssh and then connecting to mysql on the server?

Comment: no, the connections are all coming from php scripts on webservers that do queries to the external (my) MySQL server.

Comment: Do you keep the connections open while checking for the IP's or do you close them after the queries.

Comment: they were closed but even by removing the close the result stays the same...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using tcpdump and filter on port 3306. This works fine.